# Terminal recognises ImageMagick only after installation

Tags: command-line, imagemagick, oh-my-zsh

If I install ImageMagick it works fine, but the next time I start up my terminal the commands aren't being recognised anymore. (command not found: convert)

Am I forgetting to do something crucial after installation? Or could it be the shell I use for my terminal ([oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh))?

Comment: Where did you install it to? Which directory? You need to put that directory in your PATH by editing your `zsh` profile in your login directory.

Comment: Basically you need to edit your `$HOME/.zshrc` and do `export PATH=/path/to/imagemagick:$PATH`

Comment: I don't have permission to enter `$HOME/.zshrc`, can it be that it's `$HOME/.oh-my-zsh` in my case? If I installed imagemagick in `$HOME`, wil `export PATH=/Users/myUserName/ImageMagick-6.9.1:$PATH` be the right command?

Comment: It could well be that file. Run `find $HOME -name convert` to find the path to IM's  `convert`.